# Syncano - logout Facebook user

Tags: android, syncano

How to logout user using Android Syncano SDK that has login using Facebook?
I this sufficient to logout using Facebook SDK such as:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Or anything more is suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user logged in, his api key is remembered. Library will try to use this api key in next calls and it may still work. You should call:

```
syncano.setUser(null);
```